# Square bracket syntax for method definition on an object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, syntax

Looking at some custom `[Symbol.iterator]` tutorial, I came across this syntax and I don't get what's going on under the hood.

Here's a simplified version. I'm confused about how `[obj1.prop2]()` actually works.

```js
const obj1 = {
  prop1: "I'm a prop",
};

const obj2 = {
  [obj1.prop2]() {
    console.log("what am I?");
  },
  obj2prop: "I'm a property",
  obj2meth() {
    console.log("I'm a method");
  },
};
```

If I use a `for..in` loop, there's no `prop2` on `obj1`, but I can call `obj2[obj1.prop2]();`.
A loop on `obj2` gets me an `undefined` prop.

```js
for (p in obj2) {
  console.log("obj2 props: ", p);
}

// obj2 props:  undefined
// obj2 props:  obj2prop
// obj2 props:  obj2meth
```

So I'm guessing the engine creates a reference to this method bound to `obj2` somehow? I'm assuming it has something to do with the execution context, but I could be way off… I'd love some pointer in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: `[obj1.prop2]` is a fancy way of naming a method `"undefined"`, since `obj1.prop2` is `undefined`. You could call it as `obj2.undefined()`, `obj2["undefined"]()`, `obj2[undefined]()` or `obj2[obj1.prop2]()` - all the same.

Comment: This actually answers my question (I was overthinking things…) whereas linking to something about computed property names doesn't. Thanks Bergi!